# saving MP3 with java

Tags: java, save, mp3, fileoutputstream

I have a mp3 that i would like to play and save, i can play it without problems, but i can't save it.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                int bytesRead;
                try (InputStream is = conn.getInputStream()) {
                    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("‪output2.mp3‪")) {

                        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                int bytesRead;
                try (InputStream is = conn.getInputStream()) {
                    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("H:\\TestFolder2\\test.mp3")) {

                        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This doesnt work as well!

Comment: Your first snippet has LRE characters before and after `output2.mp3`. Don't know if that is relevant